# How to retrieve all the charges for a specific customer in Stripe using the customer ID?

Tags: python

I have the customer ID for a specific customer in Stripe. How can I retrieve all the charge objects for this customer?

The customer object can be retrieved using the following code:

```
Customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(customerId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

```
    Charges=stripe.Charge.list(customer=customerId)
```

Comment: Please revise, the full code is:     Charges=stripe.Charge.list(customer=customerId)

Comment: sorry, you didn't state what you wanted to do with it, so I was unaware you wanted to store it in a variable

Comment: The edit is actually for the argument part:  customer=customerId. If you don't use option "customer=" in the argument the code will not work

Comment: oh oh oh oh sorry haha

Comment: It won't let me edit it :(

Comment: I edited :) it is in the queue for approval. thanks.

Comment: I just approved it :)